# How to prevent CSS of the page affecting my widget?

Tags: javascript, css, widget

I am building widget with JS and without iframe. I need some help on how to prevent styles from page affecting my widget. Initially i build it with shadow dom, but it has no support for firefox.

Comment: Can you can assign class to your widget which are different from your page

Comment: @brk What if the page uses an element selector? Class name won't be able to protect it.

Answer (score 0):

If your don't want your CSS to affect your widget at all, you necessarily need to either:

1. Overwrite each style manually for your widget, or
2. Use an iframe

Using JavaScript for an iframe is allowed if your are under the same domain, which in this case wouldn't be a problem for you.

Comment: I ended up injecting style tag in the widget wrapper and aplying Meyer reset. I don't know if that will affect other styles on the page. I need to do it with inline javascript css. That is a task. I don't know should I use iframe because they want to inspect my js and dom skills. That is what they are saying in the test...

Comment: Yes @Alexa applying a CSS reset inline will definitely affect other styles on the page. You can probably add a class to the widget's container (i.e. myClass) and add that class to each line of the reset. For example .myClass p{...} .myClass a{...}, etc. In that way you won't affect other styles on that page.